Как вносить правки в apache/guacamole-client?
Всем привет.
Дали задачу разобраться как вносить правки в код guacamole-client. Например изменить стиль чего-то, размеры, события и все в таком духе.
По документашке не могу понять, вроде установила все необходимые зависимости, делаю git clone https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client
Но запустить не могу
Может здесь есть кто-то, кто уже разбирался и может подсказать в каком направлении двигаться, может я что-то не то делать пыталась
